# ceph-deploy mon create failing with exception

Tags: ceph

I am installing a ceph-cluster with one monitor node and one osd.
I am following the document: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/v0.86/start/quick-ceph-deploy/

During the step 5: Add the initial monitor(s) and gather the keys (new in ceph-deploy v1.1.3),

I am getting the following exception:

```
**[ceph-mon1][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**
[ceph-mon1][WARNIN] monitor: mon.ceph-mon1, might not be running yet
[ceph-mon1][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.ceph-mon1.asok mon_status
**[ceph-mon1][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ceph-mon1][WARNIN] monitor ceph-mon1 does not exist in monmap**

Just for reference my **ceph.conf** is as follows:
*[global]

fsid = 351948ba-9716-4a04-802d-28b5510bfeb0

mon_initial_members = ceph-mon1,ceph-admin,ceph-osd1

mon_host = xxx.yyy.zzz.78,xxx.yyy.zzz.147,xxx.yyy.zzz.135

auth_cluster_required = cephx

auth_service_required = cephx

auth_client_required = cephx

filestore_xattr_use_omap = true

osd_pool_default_size = 2

public_addr = xxx.yyy.zzz.0*
```

I tried to understand all the questions related to sane on ceph user mailing list but there is no precise solution I found for this problem.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same errors was able to resolve the issue by adding my other **ceph node's hostname & IpAdrress and by adding "public_network ="**

The sections which I tweaked in **ceph.conf** are:

```
mon_initial_members =
mon_host =
public_network =
```

**cat /etc/ceph/ceph.conf**

```
[global]
fsid = 33cb5c76-a685-469e-8cdd-fee7c98c3f4d
mon_initial_members = ceph1,ceph2
mon_host = 192.168.61.39,192.168.61.40
auth_cluster_required = cephx
auth_service_required = cephx
auth_client_required = cephx
filestore_xattr_use_omap = true
public_network = 192.168.61.0/24
```

And the running the command:

```
$ ceph-deploy --overwrite-conf mon create <ceph-node>
```

Comment: I have all those config correct but still seeing same error :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue...

My problem was that the alias hostname in my /etc/hosts on my deployment server and my target server was with a different hostname ....

Always make sure your hostname on the server is the same in the ceph.conf and the correct IP- HOSTNAME are the same in /etc/hosts on your deployment box ...